# How to say array[i+1] in python using for loop

Tags: python, list

I wrote this code in JavaScript:

```
let b = [10, 20, 3, 4, 5, 30, 44, 90, 100];
let pairNum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  if (b[i] % 10 == 0) {
    if (b[i + 1] % 10 == 0) {
      pairNum+= 1;
    }
  }
}
console.log(pairNum);
```

But I can't write the same code in Python because b[i+1] is not allowed. Does anyone know how to write it similar in Python?

This is my code in Python :

```
b = [10, 20, 3, 4, 5, 30, 44, 90, 100]
pairNum= 0

for i in range (1, len(b)):
    if(b[i]%10 == 0):
        if(b[i+1]%10 == 0):
            pairNum+= 1
        
            
print(pairNum)
```

Comment: Why isn't `b[i+1]` allowed in Python?

Comment: I keep getting this error:  ` if(b[i+1]%10 == 0):
IndexError: list index out of range `

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Edit the question with your python code please.

Comment: It's not allowed when `i` is the index of the last element. But you should stop before that, since there's no reason to compare the last element with the next element.

Comment: Change `len(b)` to `len(b)-1`

Comment: Why are you starting from `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: @Barmar this worked! thank you very much to everyone who reached out so quick

Comment: You are checking `undefined % 10 == 0` in JS, by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `range(1, len(b))` to `range(len(b)-1)`.

Your code is ignoring the first element because it starts the iteration at `i = 1`, and trying to access the element after the last element.

Or you could keep your existing range, and use `b[i-1]` and `b[i]` instead of `b[i]` and `b[i+1`].

You can also use `zip()` to pair each element with the following element. Since `zip()` stops when it gets to the end of the shortest input, you won't go outside the list.

```
for curnum, nextnum in zip(b, b[1:]):
    if curnum % 10 == 0 and nextnum % 10 == 0:
        pairNum += 1
```

Comment: You could even pair that with sum: `sum(not (x+y) % 10 for x, y in zip(b, b[1:]))`

Comment: Yeah, I thought about mentioning that, but decided not to throw too many variants in.

Comment: `(x + y) % 10` is not the same thing. That will count `4,6`

Comment: Ahh yes, my mistake. So then `sum(not(x%10 and y%10) for x, y in zip(b, b[1:]))`